# Wordpress append to HEAD from within shortcode callback

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am making a plugin, to register a shortcode, which when used like this: `[append_css mycss]` it will look for a custom field called `mycss` and add the contents to the `head` of the document. It all works great, except that the code is being added to the body, and I don't know how to get it to add to the head.

I have tried adding an action `wp_head` but I don't know how to pass variables whilst doing that, and it does not seem to fire from within the shortcode callback anyway.

```
function append_css_short($params){
  global $post;
  if(sizeof($params)){
    $key = $params[0];
  } else {
    $key = 'css';
  }
  return '<style type="text/css">'.
  get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true)
  .'</style>';
}
add_shortcode('append_css','append_css_short');
```

How would I get this to write to the head instead of body?
Is there a better approach to the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print something to the head of the document you need use `add_action` with `wp_head` hook.

A better approach might be to not use a shortcode at all.  Shortcodes are intended to add content or modify content.  Instead create a function that you can attach to `wp_head` that will print your css.  You may want to force the user to keep the custom field name consistent.  Or better yet have your plugin add a metabox to posts that they can enter custom css into.  Then you will always be certain of the name of the field.

```
function append_css() {

   global $post;

   if ( ! get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'mypluginname_css', true ) ) {
      return;
   }

   return '<style type="text/css">'. get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true) .'</style>';

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'append_css' );
```

The only thing i am not certain of is whether or not `$post` with the custom field data will be available outside the loop.  So you may have to add some extra querying in there to pull the custom data at the time that `wp_head` is fired.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great suggestion. I think `$post` is ok if you make it global inside the function. I will test it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: You are correct, J, my apologies. Upvoted, wrong answer deleted.

Comment: Good stuff, thanks. Ran this as a straight function with the Custom Fields as suggested.  Much easier than trying to hack through the shortcode method.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

With some minor adjustments to the answer provided by @Jrod, here is the complete working plugin, with usage as follows:

1. Create custom field called `append_css` (or `append_js`) with required code
2. ... of course, there is no number 2 ;)

## Code

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Append_CSS_JS
 * @version 0.1
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Append CSS JS
Plugin URI: http://itaccess.org/wordpress-plugins/append-css-js/
Description: Append Css or Js to any page using Custom Fields
Author: Billy Moon
Version: 0.1
Author URI: http://billy.itaccess.org/
*/

function append_css() {

  global $post;

  if ( ! get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'append_css', true ) ){
    return;
  }

  echo '<style type="text/css">'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'append_css', true) .'</style>';

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'append_css' );

function append_js() {

   global $post;

   if ( ! get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'append_js', true ) ) {
      return;
   }

   echo '<script type="text/javascript">'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'append_js', true) .'</script>';

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'append_js' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible that way, because shortcodes will be called after `wp_head()`, so you cannot hook on it.

Here's the list of all wordpress hooks http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks

**EDIT:**

Here's a workaround:

In your template:

```
<?php
//get the content of your post:
if(have_posts()) while(have_posts()) the_post();
    $pcontent = get_the_content();
endwhile;
?>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<?php echo $pcontent; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So how do you think I could go about adding a string of text to the head, from within a shortcode?

Comment: it is for a page, but it would be good if it could go for posts too I guess - for the future.