# Wordpress Plugin change head in shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, head

I'm making a wordpress plugin that uses shortcodes to display car information. But now I need to add the facebook meta tags to the head of a page. This meta is generated in the shortcode because it contains info of a car.

I know the head can't just be edited with wordpress because the shortcodes execute after the head is created (I think). But is there a way around to change the content in the head within a shortcode?

Here is an example of the meta data:

```
<!-- FACEBOOK METAS -->
<meta property="og:url" content="<<-- voertuig_url_cms -->>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<<-- merk -->> <<-- model -->> <<-- uitvoering -->> - <<-- bedrijf -->> - <<-- plaats -->>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<<-- voertuig_foto1 -->>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<<-- bedrijf -->>" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="nl_NL" />
<!-- FACEBOOK METAS -->
```

In the shortcode it will replace all the <<-- -->> for the right information. After thats done, it should be placed in the head of the page.

Until now I only know one way to do this. That is by just generating the whole page. Get the page, add the meta and display the page again. But I think that it will make the pages very slow.

I know it should be possible, because there already exists plugins which do this, but I cannot find how.

Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at [Action_Reference/wp_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) .

Comment: possible duplicate: [Wordpress append to HEAD from within shortcode callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649733/wordpress-append-to-head-from-within-shortcode-callback)

Comment: But how could I do this within my shortcode function?

Comment: It says that I could better not do this in the shortcode. But how can I change this function for every page then?

Comment: You could add input fields to every post/page/whatever. And then read informations out of them and put into head. Just like [Yoast SEO](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo) does. But thats off-topic.

Comment: Creating the whole page using shortcode is the best option you have...